# Laravel Request Macro With Static Values

Tags: php, laravel, request, lazy-loading

I was trying to create a lazy-loading pattern in a Request macro that would cache the value for the life of the request.

I put this in my `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` `boot()` function:

```php
Request::macro('foo', function() {
    static $bar;

    if (is_null($bar)) {
        $bar = 'was not null';
        return 'was null';
    }

    return $bar;
});
```

Every time I call `request()->foo()` or `Request::foo()` it returns 'was null'.

My question is two-fold:

1. How should I accomplish this pattern?
2. Why doesn't it work as written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can accomplish the pattern this way:

```php
Request::macro('foo', function() {
    if (! isset(request()->bar)) {
        request()->bar = 'was not null';
        return 'was null';
    }

    return request()->bar;
});
```

I haven't found my answer to #2, though.